# In dagster sensors is there a way to re run a RunRequest for a run key

Tags: python, dagster

I have a sensor, whenever there is a new file in my file system it will create a run request with file path as run_key. And a asset job will be invoked. That job will fetch the file and do some operations and write it to an external database.

But it is possible that the external database write could fail so I need to re try the file at a different point of time. I don't want to add a retry mechanism in the asset materialization. So is there a way to make dagster to invalidate the run request and allow me to invoke the run request again with the same filepath ?

Comment: Did you find how to do that?